# Cannot spawn a simple server in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have a simple server:

```
-module(simple_server).
-export([loop/0]).

loop() ->
    receive 
    {fact, N, Sender} ->
        Sender ! {factResult, fact(N), self()},
        loop();
    {fib, N, Sender} ->
        Sender ! {fibResult, fib(N), self()},
        loop();
    {stop, Sender} ->
        Sender ! ok
    end.

fact(0) -> 1;
fact(N) -> N * fact(N - 1).

fib(N) -> fib(N, 1, 0).

fib(0, _B, A) -> A;
fib(N, B, A) -> fib(N-1, A+B, B).
```

Then I get this:

```
...\code>erl simple_server.erl

Eshell V5.7.5  (abort with ^G)
1> Server = spawn('server@myserver', fun simple_server:loop/0).

=ERROR REPORT==== 28-Jun-2010::10:46:29 ===
** Can not start erlang:apply,[#Fun<simple_server.loop.0>,[]] on server@myserver**
<0.33.0>
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not look like you have started as a distributed node. I get the same error message when my shell erlang node is started without a short name / long name using the "-sname" / "-name" flag of [erl](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html).

If you start this shell so it can participate in distribution you must also make sure the code for simple_server is loaded at the remote node, or that the remote node can autoload it from its code path.

For interactive use, you can use the `nc(File)` or `nl(Module)` commands in the shell to load on all known nodes. Use `net_adm:ping(Node)` to ping the node if it is not already listed when you do `erlang:nodes()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should read documentation first. Some tutorial would be helpful.

1. erl with module source code doesn't anything. Read `erl -man erl` for more info.
2. `erlang:apply\2` has `Node` as first argument but `Node` should exists and have to be connected to current node.

You should try:

```
$ erl
Erlang R13B04 (erts-5.7.5) [source] [smp:2:2] [rq:2] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.7.5  (abort with ^G)
1> c(simple_server).
{ok, simple_serevr}
2> spawn(simple_server, loop, []).
<0.33.0>
3>
```

As good starting point you can look at [Learn You Some Erlang For Great Good](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/).